# MVC ValidationSummary behaviour

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-5

I have `@Html.ValidationSummary(true)`
So it do not displaying any model property errors

But if I add custom model error on controller action(this one is not model property error):

```
ModelState.AddModelError("send-email", "Your massage wasn't send, please try again");
```

Than or some reason `@Html.ValidationSummary(true)` do not displaying that custom error, only if I set `@Html.ValidationSummary(false)` it will display that error plus all the rest property errors, what I do not want, I want `ValidationSummary` display just custom `"send-email"` error.

Is there anything I can do about that?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't specify a key then you essentially return a generic error.

Try

```
ModelState.AddModelError(
    string.Empty, "Your massage wasn't send, please try again");
```